# How can I put a condition to check if an element has been clicked?

Tags: python, selenium

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    import pyautogui
    
    web = webdriver.Chrome()
    print("trying to run the program")
    
    yeah = web.get("https://www.google.com")
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    searchbar = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
    
    
    if  pyautogui.click() == web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'):
        searchbar.send_keys("yeah! We did it!")
```

I want the program to detect whether user has click on Search Bar and then send keys on the search bar (for ex. Take the google search bar). I want to send the keys if only user has clicked on the search bar. How can I do that?
(ignore the code, that's just for presentation).

Comment: It's difficult to answer for sure without trying it or seeing html before/after a button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect selected element in most cases. But not in all the cases.
Sometimes that element changes or adds some class name, in others some attribute is changed, sometimes some other element attribute is changed.
It depends on the page you are working with.
For example on Google Home page with not logged user you can do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui
    
web = webdriver.Chrome()
print("trying to run the program")
    
yeah = web.get("https://www.google.com")
    
time.sleep(5)
    
indicator_el = web.find_element_by_css_selector('div.UUbT9')
indicator_style = indicator_el.get_attribute("style")
if "none" in indicator_style:
    print("search bar not clicked")
```

Comment: Ah, take google search bar for example. I wan't to do it as fast I can, Can you please help? Stuck in this problem from few weeks. Please help

Comment: What exactly did not work? Do you see any exception? What is the value of `indicator_style` you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the search bar in google is clicked the style attribute become blank

[image: When Search bar is clicked]

**Code**
You may try below code utilizing above condition:

```
Searchbar = web.driver_find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']")
Searchbar.click()
Autocomplete= web.driver_find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='UUbT9']")
if(Autocomplete.get_attribute("style")=="")
  Searchbar.send_keys("yeah! We did it!")
```

Comment: it send the keys on it's own

Comment: on its own means